# PHP search directory for matching file size(s)

Tags: php, arrays

How do I take a file size I've got, e.g. 100928 bytes, and search in a directory for any matching file sizes and return those as an array? I'm looking to hunt up duplicate files.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) There should be lots of resources how to search a directory in PHP. And saving file sizes in an array to check against shouldn't be too difficult either

Comment: So you want to search through files which are equal to a file size?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet..I'm new to this still and haven't found anything (been searching for half an hour and haven't turned anything up except DirectoryIterator but no clear guidelines on how to apply it). @Rizier123 yes!

Comment: @Micah Can you please explain why did you accepted the other answer?! 1. It only grabs `*.txt` files and 2. it compares it with the wrong value!?!

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 I think the `scandir` only returns file and directory names without sizes so that didn't work (it threw up an error for each file in the directory). Using the `glob` method worked.

Comment: @Micah Did you changed the dir name to your dir name? It must work! Also glob returns also only files and not the filesize!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

```
$results = array();
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    if (filesize($filename) == 1024000) {
        $results[] = $filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $result = array();

    foreach(scandir("DIR NAME") as $file) {

        if(filesize($file) == 100928) 
            $result[] = $file;

    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```